# How to populate a table by looking up columns in another table?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula, timetable

[image: Screenshot of tables]

I have a table (left) where I am defining, per row, the date/time of lessons for an individual.

I have a second table (right) which is my resulting timetable.

I am trying to use formula to populate the timetable based on the planning table - but without luck.  I have tried multiple INDEX/MATCH formula plundered from web searches... but none achieve the correct result.

Each cell in the timetable, defined by their relative Time row value and Day column header values, should be populated with the corresponding Initials value where the Time/Day combo map to the Session/Day columns of the planning table.

Hence `TUESDAY`, `09:00-09:30` on the timetable should be calculated as `AB`, because cells `K3` (**Day**) and `L3` (**Time**) are mapped in the planning table - with the resulting Initials being `AB` (cell `C3`).

Hopefully the image will explain better than my words.

All suggestions gratefully received.

Links to sources I have tried:

- [www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-7-ways-to-lookup-value-based-on.html](http://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-7-ways-to-lookup-value-based-on.html)
- [www.careerprinciples.com/resources/index-match-with-multiple-criteria#:~:text=array%5D%2C0](http://www.careerprinciples.com/resources/index-match-with-multiple-criteria#:%7E:text=array%5D%2C0)))-,To%20perform%20an%20INDEX%20MATCH%20with%20multiple%20criteria%20in%20Excel,inputs%20in%20the%20MATCH%20formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then I believe this should do what you are looking for:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>Q2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table1[[Session 1 - Day]:[Session 3 - Time]])/2),
     b, TOCOL(IFS(a,Table1[Initials])),
     c, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Table1[[Session 1 - Day]:[Session 3 - Time]]),2),
     d, HSTACK(b,c),
     XLOOKUP(1,($P2=INDEX(d,,3))*(Q$1=INDEX(d,,2)),TAKE(d,,1),""))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down and fill right!. However, you can use the following one as well, which spills for the whole data.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>Q2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table1[[Session 1 - Day]:[Session 3 - Time]])/2),
     b, TOCOL(IFS(a,Table1[Initials])),
     c, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Table1[[Session 1 - Day]:[Session 3 - Time]]),2),
     d, HSTACK(b,c),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(P2:P13),COLUMNS(Q1:U1),LAMBDA(_r,_c,XLOOKUP(1,
     (INDEX(P2:P13,_r)=INDEX(d,,3))*(INDEX(Q1:U1,_c)=INDEX(d,,2)),TAKE(d,,1),""))))
```

---

**Note:** From the screenshots of the post, looks like you are using `Structured References` aka `Tables`, therefore I have used tables in the formulas above and name of the table is `Table1` makesure to change the name in the formula as per suit.

---

Another way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>Q2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, _Int&"|"&_Day&"|"&_Time,
     b, IFS(ISERROR(LEFT(TEXTAFTER(a,"|"))/1),a),
     c, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(b,3),"|",{1,2,3}),"|"),
     MAKEARRAY(ROWS(P2:P13),COLUMNS(Q1:U1),LAMBDA(_r,_c,XLOOKUP(1,
     (INDEX(P2:P13,_r)=INDEX(c,,3))*(INDEX(Q1:U1,_c)=INDEX(c,,2)),TAKE(c,,1),""))))
```

---

Where:

`_Day` refers to `=Table1[[Session 1 - Day]:[Session 3 - Time]]`

`_Int` refers to `=Table1[Initials]`

`_Time` refers to `=Table1[[Session 1 - Time]:[Session 3 - Time]]`

are defined named ranges which will automatically grab the structured references for a new entry in the records.

[image]

---

Comment: Fantastic, I learnt a lot from your answers!  I used your first version, but am confident the others would work equally.. thank you.

Comment: @GuyCordran glad to know it worked out for you =)